# How can I compute my data frame by slicing the index

Tags: python, pandas

I have the data as

```
A=[0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9,1.1,1.3,1.5,1.7] 
B=[3,4,6,8,2,10,2,3,4]
```

If A is my index and B is the value corresponding to A. I have to group the first three i.e `[0.1,0.3,0.5]` and calculate the average in B i.e `[3,4,6]`. similarly average of 2nd 3 data `[8,2,10]` corresponding to `[0.7,0.9,1.1]` and again of `[2,3,4]` corresponding to `[1.3,1.5,1.7]` and then prepare the table for this three average values. Final Data frame should be like

```
A=[1,2,3]
B=[average 1, average 2, average 3]
```

Answer (score 1):

If need aggregate `mean` by each 3 values use helper array by length of DataFrame with integer division by 3 with [`GroupBy.mean`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html):

```
A=[0.1,0.3,0.5,0.7,0.9,1.1,1.3,1.5,1.7] 
B=[3,4,6,8,2,10,2,3,4]
 
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':B}, index=A)
print (df)
     col
0.1    3
0.3    4
0.5    6
0.7    8
0.9    2
1.1   10
1.3    2
1.5    3
1.7    4
df = df.groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 3).mean()
df.index +=1
print (df)
        col
1  4.333333
2  6.666667
3  3.000000
```